# Excel 2007 Macro - Make Username using first initial of first name and full last name

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I'm looking for a macro that will create usernames based on the first initial of the first name and the entire last name. In doing some research, I found this article [here][1] which looked like the exact answer to my question.

I'm new to the excel macro world and was having issues adapting the answers found on the linked page to my specific excel file. My username column is (B), first name (D), and the last name is (E). Based on a set up such as this, I was hoping someone could help me with the proper macro. There are about 600+ entries and having this would make life much easier. And more importantly, I'd like to know how to do it :)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need a macro, a formula will do it.

in B1:

```
=left(D1,1) & E1
```

Drag down

If you want it in uppercase then wrap in in an upper statement and if you want it in lowercase wrap it in a lower statement